# Maven YAML resolve error in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a Spring Boot (Jhipster generated) project. When I run my project using `./mvnw` it works well BUT when I try `mvn package` or `mvn clean install` it crashes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.hotspot.path.audio' in value "${application.hotspot.path.audio}"
```

and

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.hotspot.path.audio' in value "${application.hotspot.path.audio}"
```

My YAML configuartion (it's fine, checked it):

```
application:
    gateway: 192.168.0.1
    host: 192.168.0.2
    hotspot:
        path:
            audio: my-audio-config
```

My ApplicationProperties class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
public class ApplicationProperties {
    @Value("${application.hotspot.path.audio}")
    private String audioPath;
    ...getters/setters...
}
```

Full consolelog:

```
▶ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Arch 3 D 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default-resources) @ arch-3-d ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 62 resources
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ arch-3-d ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 62 resources
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ arch-3-d ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ arch-3-d ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/fury/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/fury/GitProjects/qp_web/server-side/target/test-results/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) @ arch-3-d ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 177 source files to /home/fury/GitProjects/qp_web/server-side/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ arch-3-d ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ arch-3-d ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ arch-3-d ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/fury/GitProjects/qp_web/server-side/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.qitsoftware.arch3d.config.WebConfigurerTest
2018-01-21 23:58:06.178  INFO   --- [           main] c.q.arch3d.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application configuration, using profiles: prod
2018-01-21 23:58:06.210  INFO   --- [           main] c.q.arch3d.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application fully configured
2018-01-21 23:58:06.306  INFO   --- [           main] c.q.arch3d.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application configuration, using profiles: dev
2018-01-21 23:58:06.307  INFO   --- [           main] c.q.arch3d.config.WebConfigurer          : Web application fully configured
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.347 sec - in com.qitsoftware.arch3d.config.WebConfigurerTest
Running com.qitsoftware.arch3d.repository.CustomAuditEventRepositoryIntTest

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2018-01-21 23:58:08.133  INFO 11054 --- [           main] .q.a.r.CustomAuditEventRepositoryIntTest : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-21 23:58:10.458  INFO 11054 --- [           main] c.q.arch3d.config.MetricsConfiguration   : Initializing Metrics Log reporting
2018-01-21 23:58:13.746  WARN 11054 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.hotspot.path.audio' in value "${application.hotspot.path.audio}"
2018-01-21 23:58:13.781 ERROR 11054 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.hotspot.path.audio' in value "${application.hotspot.path.audio}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.hotspot.path.audio' in value "${application.hotspot.path.audio}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:831)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        ... 42 common frames omitted

2018-01-21 23:58:13.784 ERROR 11054 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@6721e0a5] to prepare test instance [com.qitsoftware.arch3d.repository.CustomAuditEventRepositoryIntTest@4fa60a55]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.hotspot.path.audio' in value "${application.hotspot.path.audio}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.hotspot.path.audio' in value "${application.hotspot.path.audio}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:831)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You shouldn’t be mixing `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties` on the same class. `@Component` on a configuration properties class is somewhat atypical too. You probably want to use `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on a class that consumes the properties instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have not to repeat the prefix : `application`.

So this should be fine :

```
@Value("${hotspot.path.audio}")
private String audioPath;
```

Comment: Also tried it but it didn't help. You see, app works fine. The problem is when I run it through maven tasks

Comment: Could you edit your question with the whole output (command execution + exception) ?

Comment: Yes, added. Check it out :)

Comment: Fine ! I think that the YAML file is not in the classpath and mvnw probably adds it as it runs the spring boot application. If you can edit mvnw content in the question, it could help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how it works for you when you do `./mvnw`. It cannot work, because you have specified

```
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
```

which means spring will search for property like
 `application.application.hotspot.path.audio`
which it cannot find.

Two options.
1. Just specify  `@ConfigurationProperties`
2

```
@Value("${hotspot.path.audio}")
 private String audioPath;
```

Comment: No, didn't work. I've applied your suggession but somehow the app worked even with my configs :D